# Dialog-element disapears behind media-element in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, primefaces

Following issue: We are using the p:media tag to load a pdf document. Through user interaction  a separate dialog-window is opened. This works fine using Firefox or Chrome. Is using IE (confirmed in 9 & 10) the pdf document remains in the foreground while the dialog is pushed into the background.

We tried to fiddle around with z-index values with no success. Is there a solution that IE displays the dialog in front off the displayed pdf-file? I'm thankful for any help.

[image: Cut off dialog element in IE 9 & 10]

Comment: Try this approach: [flash-overlays-thickbox-on-internet-explorer][1]

Jens


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788951/flash-overlays-thickbox-on-internet-explorer

Comment: Hi @osterhase... Have you solved this? how?

Comment: @KishorP: No, not yet.